# How to change text from label from another form visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim NewMDIChild1 As New Form2()
    Dim NewMDIChild2 As New Form3()

    Private Sub Form1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Form1ToolStripMenuItem.Click
        NewMDIChild1 = New Form2
        NewMDIChild1.MdiParent = Me
        NewMDIChild1.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Form2ToolStripMenuItem.Click
        NewMDIChild2 = New Form3
        NewMDIChild2.MdiParent = Me
        NewMDIChild2.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CloseToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CloseToolStripMenuItem.Click
        If Not ActiveMdiChild Is Nothing Then
            ActiveMdiChild.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CloseTodoToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CloseTodoToolStripMenuItem.Click
        While Not ActiveMdiChild Is Nothing
            ActiveMdiChild.Close()
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SmallToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SmallToolStripMenuItem.Click
Form2.Label1.Text = "test"
    End Sub

    Private Sub MediumToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MediumToolStripMenuItem.Click
Form2.Label1.Text = "test"
    End Sub

    Private Sub BigToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BigToolStripMenuItem.Click
Form2.Label1.Text = "test"
    End Sub
End Class
```

What I want to do is change the size of a label, the problem is that the label is in another form and it doesnt seem to be changing. I was using this "Form2.Label1.Text = "test"" just to see if the label changed. I think it's because im using the MDIChild. Could anyone help me ?

Comment: Can you show the code where you reference the form and make an attempt to size it / set the Text property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not showing code that's relevant to your question, nowhere you're changing any text on any label, so I'm going to ignore 99% of that huge code block and boil down your question to this:

> ```
> Dim NewMDIChild1 As New Form2()
> Dim NewMDIChild2 As New Form3()
> ```
>
> *I was using this "Form2.Label1.Text = "test""*

I'm not sure if VB.NET behaves the same way as VB6/VBA here, but if you're not getting an exception with `Form2.Label1.Text = "test"` then it probably is the case - you're setting the text of the label on the *default instance* of the form, and your class `Form1` is referring to `Form2` using an object reference named `NewMDIChild1`.

Depending on where you had that test code, doing `NewMDIChild1.Label1.Text = "text"` should produce the expected results.